# person detection from series/collection of images using java

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have collection of images(may be 10) of one person from different angles
I need to detect this person.

We can use these initial 10 images for training/feature extraction
and when another(11th) image is given as input, we need to detect person in that image

I need to code in Java
any help/links are most welcome.
Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question decently I'd need more information. Are you interested in detecting specifically that person? Are there any characteristics of that person that could be easily exploited with machine learning techniques? Are you able to get hold of any more training data? Is there any way I could see the pictures?

As a start:

You could use a [neural net](http://www.jeffheaton.com/ai/) but I suspect you may need more training data for that to be effective, in any case certainly worth learning about.

You could also try [convolution masks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) made up of different parts of the image (it would be interesting to see which features are the best indicator).

You could try using a Hough Transform (search for this on Wikipedia). If you are just interested in detecting whether a person (any person) is present in the image you could look for ovals.

Comment: Thanks for that
Actually this is a small assignment of our project in which
"a robot follows a person"

So it will be mostly based on that persons shirt color. We can use any number of training images(10 which I mentioned was just for example)

So its kind of content based image identification
I got one good link:
http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp

but this thing just gives entire image. I need to identify that content. I need border around that person.

please help.

Comment: If you are attempting to follow a person, then perhaps it might be simpler if you initialised a tracker when the person was in view, and then tracked them in subsequent frames, rather than trying to repetitively detect them. Of course, the initialisation could be carried out by your detector if that was preferable.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but as I mentioned I just have to deal with the small assignment of that project.

i.e. to detect a person given colletion of images.